How to Disable Copying of PDF Content in QLPreviewController?
This is my code, when i use QLPreviewController to preview the pdf files,the left area will happen a view,this view could copy the pdf view,i don't want this future,cloud hidden this copy button?
import UIKit
import QuickLook

class PDFResolve: UIViewController, QLPreviewControllerDataSource, QLPreviewControllerDelegate {
    
    private let previewController = QLPreviewController()
    private var tempURL: URL?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // 加载根目录下的data.pdf文件
        if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "pdf") {
            let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            tempURL = fileURL
        }
        
        previewController.dataSource = self
        previewController.delegate = self
        
        addChild(previewController)
        previewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        previewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.view.addSubview(previewController.view)
        previewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        // 隐藏默认的按钮
        previewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        previewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
        
        previewController.reloadData()
    }
    
    // MARK: - QLPreviewControllerDataSource
    
    func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
        return tempURL == nil ? 0 : 1
    }
    
    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
        return tempURL! as QLPreviewItem
    }
    
    // MARK: - QLPreviewControllerDelegate
    
    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, shouldOpen url: URL, for previewItem: QLPreviewItem) -> Bool {
        // 阻止用户打开或拷贝PDF文件
        return false
    }
    
    func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, editingModeFor previewItem: QLPreviewItem) -> QLPreviewItemEditingMode {
        // 禁用拷贝功能
        return .disabled
    }
}

enter image description here
I read the document of QLPreviewController,but i can't find the method to resolve,i want to hidden the button

Thank you for your response, but my target audience consists of professional users who do not have vision impairments.
